# Detect newline in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How can I detect when I press the return button on the on-screen keyboard which creates a newline in the EditText field.

I don't really care if I have to check for newline characters or the return key, but I want to send a message by pressing the return key on the keyboard.

I already tried a few different things, but I can't seem to get it working.

My EditText object is called `chatInputET` if you want to know.

Comment: Most answer is not comprehensive. To detect when user enter new line anywhere in your text, you can use my solution at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479592/android-catch-new-line-break-on-multiline-edit-text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add listener to your input:

```
chatInputET.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher(){
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged( CharSequence txt, int start, int before, int count ) {
    if( -1 != txt.toString().indexOf("\n") ){
      doSendMsg();
    }
  }
} );
```

Comment: should be `txt.toString().indexOf("\n")`, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: could even be `txt.toString().contains( "\n" )`

Comment: there is some thing wrong with your if, it works for space chars too not only new lines the answer below is the correct if -->  if (string.length() > 0 && string.charAt(string.length() - 1) == '\n')

Answer (score 4):

```
chatInputET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String string = s.toString();
    if (string.length() > 0 && string.charAt(string.length() - 1) == '\n') {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with.  I put it in the onCreate when I set up the editText.

```
editText          = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String string       = s.toString();
        if (string.length() > 0 && string.charAt(string.length() - 1) == '\n') {
            // do stuff
            // for me i get the string and write to a usb serial port
            String data     = editText.getText().toString();
            if (usbService != null)
            {
                // if UsbService was correctly binded, Send data
                usbService.write(data.getBytes());
                editText.setText("");//i clear it.
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody with a multi line EditText wanting to detect a "\n" ***typed*** ***anywhere***  this is what I came up with:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    private var oldText = editText.text.toString()

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        if (s == null) return

        val oldLineBreakCount = oldText.count { it == '\n' }
        val newLineBreakCount = s.count { it == '\n' }

        if (oldLineBreakCount < newLineBreakCount) {
            nestedScroll.smoothScrollBy(0, 64) // Scroll by the line height
        }

        if (oldLineBreakCount > newLineBreakCount) {
            nestedScroll.smoothScrollBy(0, -64)
        }

        oldText = s.toString()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun isChangeLigne(s: String?): Boolean{
        if (s != null && s.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (s[s.length - 1] == '\n') {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

This kotlin function can be used in **onTextChanged** callback with text string as parameter. Another solution is to use **editText.lineCount** property. You can check the line number with some code like:

```
var lineNumber = editText.lineCount
// in onTextChange callack
if(lineNumber!=editText.lineCount){
 // detect line change
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: I re edit the answer, hope it can be helpful. thank you for reminding me.